# Check xml file signature with parent's public key

Tags: c#, certificate

I'm creating a code that verifies the signature of an xml file through the public key of the certification authority of the certificate that signed that xml. For some reason when I check with the public key of the certificate that signed it, everything goes well, but when I use the public key of the parent, it says that the signature is invalid.

I show below both the code that signs and what it verifies.

Comments:
The CA is self-signed by an AD CS.
I don't want the crl of the certificates to be validated.

```
private void signBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(@"C:\urnaData\votos.xml");

    X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);

    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
    X509Certificate2Collection col = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByIssuerName, "CA das Urnas - CNE", true);
    foreach (X509Certificate2 x509 in col)
    {
        SignXmlDoc(doc, x509);
        File.WriteAllText(@"C:\urnaData\votes-signed.xml", doc.OuterXml);
    }
    store.Close();
}
public static void SignXmlDoc(XmlDocument doc, X509Certificate2 cert)
{
    SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(doc);
    signedXml.SigningKey = cert.GetRSAPrivateKey();
    Reference reference = new Reference();
    reference.Uri = "";
    reference.AddTransform(new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform());
    signedXml.AddReference(reference);

    KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();
    keyInfo.AddClause(new KeyInfoX509Data(cert));

    signedXml.KeyInfo = keyInfo;
    signedXml.ComputeSignature();
    XmlElement xmlSig = signedXml.GetXml();

    doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(doc.ImportNode(xmlSig, true));
}

private void testSign_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

    X509Certificate2Collection col = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByIssuerName, "CA das Urnas - CNE", true);

    foreach (X509Certificate2 x509 in col)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(@"C:\urnaData\votes-signed.xml");
        MessageBox.Show(ValidateXMLSignature(doc, x509).ToString());
    }
    store.Close();
}

public static bool ValidateXMLSignature(XmlDocument doc, X509Certificate2 cert)
{
    try
    {
        SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(doc);
        XmlNode signatureNode = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Signature")[0];
        signedXml.LoadXml((XmlElement)signatureNode);
        return signedXml.CheckSignature(cert, true);
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> For some reason when I check with the public key of the certificate that signed it, everything goes well, but when I use the public key of the parent, it says that the signature is invalid.

That sounds like everything is working correctly.  The parent/CA didn't sign the document, so their public key can't verify it.  All you can do is ask two different questions:

1. Does /this/ certificate's public key verify the signature.
2. Does /this/ certificate's issuance chain (see `X509Chain`) say that /this other/ certificate was its direct issuer?  (`s_parentCertBytes.SequenceEqual(chain.ChainElements[1].Certificate.RawData)`)

If both return true, then you have effectively written an issuer-pinning routine.  But you can't do it without the public key of the actual signing certificate.  (The easiest way to internalize that is to realize that the CA and the issued cert don't need to use the same algorithm family... e.g. the CA could have an ECDSA-based key and the issued cert have an RSA-based key... so there's no way you can sensibly ask if the ECDSA public key of the CA can corroborate the RSA signature.)